# passing array by reference in D

Tags: d

I am trying to copy the data from `matrixA` to `matrixB` in the function `M`, but I got the error:

```
app.d(20): Error: function app.M (double[][] s, ref double[][] d, int row, int col) is not callable using argument types (double[5][5], double[][], int, int)
```

Code:

```
double matrixA[5][5] = [ [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 ],  
                         [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 ],  
                         [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 ],  
                         [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 ],  
                         [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 ] ];
double matrixB[][];

void M(double[][] s, ref double[][] d, int row, int col)
{
    d.length = row;

    foreach (i; 0 .. d.length)  
        d[i].length = col;

    d = s;
}

void main()
{
    M(matrixA, matrixB, 5, 5);
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you have provided the code that you were compiling with. What you have here wouldn't compile even if what you were trying to do were correct, since you used `...` in the array definitions, and you called `M` outside of any function and with arguments that don't exist.

Comment: you can consider ... as [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 ], I'm trying to call M inside main

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two problems here. One with `ref` and one with attempting an implicit conversion that won't work.

With `ref` in D, the type must match exactly. Implicit conversion doesn't cut it. So, for instance, if you have

```
int[5] a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
int[] b = a;
```

and you have

```
void foo(int[] bar) {}
```

then both of these lines would compile

```
foo(a);
foo(b);
```

because a static array implicitly converts to a dynamic one, but if you change it so that `foo` takes its argument by ref

```
void foo(ref int[] a) {...}
```

then

```
foo(a); // won't compile, because a is int[5], not int[]
foo(b); // compiles, because b is int[]
```

So, if you have a function which takes `ref double[][]`, you have to pass it a `double[][]`. Nothing which implicitly converts to `double[][]` would work.

Now, it's worse than that, because you're passing it a `double[5][5]`, which does not implicitly convert to `double[][]`. So, even if `ref` accepted implicit conversions, your code wouldn't work, and even if you removed `ref`, your code wouldn't work. A single dimensional static array can be sliced (implicitly or explicitly) to get a dynamic one, but you can't slice a multi-dimensional static array to get a dynamic one.

```
double[5] a;
double[] b = b; // compiles
double[] c = a[]; // compiles

double[5][5] d;
double[][] e = d; // does not compile
double[][] f = d[]; // does not compile
```

AFAIK, if you want to assign a `double[5][5]` to a `double[][]`, you'd have to do something like

```
double[5][5] a;
double[][] b;

foreach(i; row; a)
    b[i] = row[];
```

Some work has been done recently on supporting user-defined types with multi-dimensional slicing, so it may be possible to slice a `double[5][5]` to `double[][]` with a syntax that I'm not aware of, but it may be something that only works with user-defined types. Regardless, there is no implicit conversion from `double[5][5]` to `double[][]`, and implicit conversions don't work with `ref`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently making multidimensional dynamic arrays play nice with static arrays is a bit difficult.

To answer your question, you can use templates to define a function that takes either:

```
void M(T)(T s, ref double[][] d, int row, int col) 
  if (is(typeof(s[0][0]) : double))
{ }
```

This declaration says that the source `s` can be any type `T` such that indexing T at 0,0 returns a double (or something implicitly convertible to a double.

However, your function body will not work as presented. You cannot just assign s to d when they may be different sizes. This may be closer to what you are looking for:

```
{
  d.length = row;

  foreach(i ; 0 .. d.length)
    d[i] = s[i][0..col].dup;
}
```